# Nginx configurations

Tags: php, configuration, nginx

I'm looking through several documents but for some reason I can't wrap my head around the configuration necessary for what I'm trying to do. Basically I want:

- All directory requests should keep their url but be processed by index.php
- All .js, .css, .jpeg and .png files in their respective directories (/js/, /css/, and /images/) should be provided without php processing.
- All other file access should be denied (including all .php).

I've tried setting up locations for the .php processing but I can never figure out how to get it working correctly. I'm going to keep at it but was hoping for some quick help as well :)

Thanks!

Edit 2: I think I came up with something decent. It may not be perfect but it should work.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    root /mypath/www;

    access_log /mypath/access.log;
    error_log /mypath/error.log;

    index index.html;

    location ^~ /app {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ \.conf {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        return 404 ;
    }

    location ~ /images/.*.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif) {
        try_files $uri $uri = 404;
        expires max;
    }

    location ~ /css/.*.css {
        try_files $uri $uri = 404;
        expires 1d;
    }

    location ~ /js/.*.js {
        try_files $uri $uri = 404;
        expires 1d;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @PHPProxy;
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 $document_root/error.html;
    }

    location @PHPProxy {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was kind of fun to think about. I've previously just made sure to block directories or make sure that I don't have any files I don't want being accessed in my doc root.

I think I found a way to do it. It doesn't actually give a 404 or 403 for other files, it just rewrites everything except the specified directories to /index.php.

Here is the config I tested with:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen your.domain.name:80;
server_name your.domain.name;

root /var/www/vhost/testing;
server_tokens off;

location ~ ^/(images|css|js)/.* {
    expires max;
}
location / {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php$1 last;
}
location ~ ^/index.php {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

So anything in /images, /css, or /js will just load, but everything else gets rewritten to the index file.

Just keep in mind that any files not in those 3 folders will be totally overlooked.

Comment: This looks similar to what I was doing but more thought-out. I'll give this a shot tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use the "try_files" directive instead of the "rewrite". IMO it's made just for what you are looking for :) http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule

Comment: @conradk I've used try_files on sites before, but I'm not sure that is what he was looking for. He wanted any files other than the specified folders to be denied and try_files kept letting them through. I would guess when you have something like `try_files $uri /index.php$uri` it does a rewrite (or something similar) internally anyway. Now, if I could combine the only allowing certain folders and trying everything else on /index.php, that would be pretty awesome.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to respond! So this almost does what I need. So it serves css, jpeg, jpg and png statically and all other requests go to index.php. What I'd like to do is continue serving the css, jpeg, jpg and png statically but ONLY send directory requests to index.php; deny EVERYTHING else. I haven't figured out quite how to do this. Any thoughts? I updated my post with my current configuration.

Comment: I updated my post with what I eventually came up with. Thanks for the help.